# Растянуть окно на весь экран в XAML

Tags: windows, xaml, wpf

Можно ли растянуть окно на весь экран при помочи XAML в wpf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `WindowState="Maximized"`.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt: Пожалуйста!